# How to avoid deprecation warning by replacing session_unregister with $SESSION[] after upgrading to PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, session, installation, deprecated

I just installed **PHP 5.3** and am weeding out consequent "**deprecated**" warnings.

It says **`session_unregister() is deprecated`** in:

```
session_unregister($serverWideUniqueIdCode);
```

and the replacement seems to be $_SESSION[].

**So what would be the syntax with `$_SESSION[]` to express the same thing?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](http://php.net/session_unregister) *(take a look at that page, it says quite some interesting stuff ;-) )* :

> session_unregister() unregisters the
>   global variable named name  from the
>   current session.

To remove an entry from an array, you can use `unset`. So, instead of

```
session_unregister('my_var');
```

You can use

```
unset($_SESSION['my_var']);
```

Which, in your case, I guess, means :

```
unset($_SESSION[$serverWideUniqueIdCode]);
```

Still, you probably don't want to call `unset` on the whole `$_SESSION` variable. Quoting the doc a second time :

> Note: If `$_SESSION` (or
>   `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS`  for PHP 4.0.6 or
>   less) is used, use `unset()` to
>   unregister a session variable. Do not
>   `unset()`  `$_SESSION` itself as this will
>   disable the special function of the
>   `$_SESSION` superglobal.

Answer (score 2):

$_SESSION = array();

Comment: I am curious if this would have the same effect as `unset($_SESSION)`. ie. Disabling the special function of session.